# VS 2010 Silverlight Application 4 (VB or C#) - How do i use the webbrowser?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, silverlight-4.0, webbrowser-control

I need some help with the WebBrowser object in VS (C# or VB) (Silverlight Application 4).
My problem is that the WebBrowser object only shows this: -

[image: WebBrowser object not active...]

How do i make it work/remove that text ? All i want to do is this:

```
C# :
MainWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri("URL HERE"));
VB :
MainWebBrowser.Navigate("URL HERE")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at this:
http://silverlight-outofbrowser.com/

Answer (score 1):

As the error message indicates, the WebBrowser control doesn't work when Silverlight is hosted in a browser.  In order to use the control, you need to be running your app outside of the browser.